# Table of contents breaks page style

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I am having a problem with my table of contents, when my TOC creates a new page the page numbering centers instead of remaining flushed right like all of the other pages of the document.

[image]

As code I am only using the `\tableofcontents` command. This also happens with `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

[image]

My page style is given by the following code:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ \fancyhf{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \fancyfoot[R]{\nouppercase{\thepage}} }
```

Comment: My page style is given by the following code: \fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\nouppercase{\thepage}}
}

Comment: Probably `\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\nouppercase{\thepage}} ` helps?

Comment: Yes that fixed it ! Thanks!!